# Problem with e.Graphics.DrawImage()

Tags: c#

This is my code and when I call this code from localhost, printer worked,but from anoder
 IP noting.I think DrawImage function not worked.Who can help me.I check the Bitmap object properly created and Image exist.

```
protected void printButton__Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument document = 
                               new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
        document.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(document_PrintPage);
        document.Print();
}

void document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
        string s = Server.MapPath("Temp.jpg");
        Bitmap objBmpImage = new Bitmap(s);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage( objBmpImage, 10, 10, 200, 100);
}
```

Comment: Many open questions...what does Server.MapPath do...what do you mean with "from another IP"...

Comment: Check the value of the string 's' in your code... might give you some clues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are in asp.net environment (`Server.MapPath`) & are assuming that you can get hold of a printer on the client machine.

If you are trying to do that, it cannot be done.
On the other hand, you can't use `Server.MapPath` in a winforms environment.

Comment: Server.MapPath properly worked.it returned path and I chked it correct.And Bitmap object is correct,I think DrawImage() function properly dosnt work,because when I run sayt from localhost it work and print data,otherwise nothing.